# PHP MYSQL display Open Status

Tags: php, mysql

I need to amend this script to only show Open records.  Field is called statusRP

```
$result = mysql_query("select id, ref, company, title, forename,
                              surname, tel, fax, mob, statusRP, email 
                       from Client");

  if (!$result) {
      die("Query to show fields from table failed");
  }

   $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result) ;
```

Comment: Everytime someone uses deprecated `mysql_*` functions a cute little kitty dies somewhere in the world.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I got to remember that one, I am definitely going to use that! FOFL

Comment: Well in that case add a WHERE clause to the query. If you dont know what a WHERE clause is [RT?M](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/)

Comment: You are going to have to tell us what datatype the statusRP column is and what data is stored in it.

Comment: Does the query you show in your question work, but just show more data than you require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding,

```
$result = mysql_query("select id, ref, company, title, forename, surname, tel, fax, mob, statusRP, email from Client WHERE Client.statusRP = 'Open'";)
```

One more thing, Use mysqli rather then mysql (if mysql is not your requirement). I think it will be work.

Comment: Dont think that is going to achieve much as there is only one table involved in the query the `Client.` is not required

Comment: If you just want to remove a comma from Pauls answer you could have just edited his answer rather than posting the same just adding an alias which make no change in the output. Please post answer if its necessary else use the edit or comment options.

Comment: Amazing dear @Veerendra .. its ok.. If you think like that then leave it ... :)

Comment: @KumarRakesh Actually this is not a kind of my personal thinkings but these are the site rules

Answer (score 0):

Query to show fields from table failed

```
 $result = mysql_query("select id, ref, company, title, forename, surname, tel, fax, mob, statusRP, email from Client, WHERE statusRP = 'Open';");

  if (!$result) {
      die("Query to show fields from table failed");
  }

   $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result) ;
```

Comment: Add extra data to your question (using the edit link) and not to an answer. As this is not an answer