# How do I add criteria to a WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filter these results with the status from c.statusRP = Open

```
  $query= mysql_query("SELECT h.id, h.sid, h.did, h.nextaction, h.nextactiondate, d.company, d.name, d.surname, c.company, d.balance, d.amount from History h, Person d, Client c where h.sid=c.ref and d.id=h.did and nextactiondate between $dayEnd and $dayStart order by c.company desc");

  #print $tquery;
  $mydate = date("d-m-Y");

  $message = "<br><br><h1>Task List for $mydate</h1><br>";

  $message .= "<table border=\"1\"><tr><strong><td>Customer Ref</td><td>Client Company</td><td>Customer Ref</td><td>Other Company</td><td>Full Name</td><td>Next Action</td></strong></tr>";

  while ($def = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {

    $sid = $def[1];
    $did = $def[2];
    $nextaction = $def[3];
    $nextactiondate = $def[4];
    $dcompany = $def[5];
    $dname = $def[6];
    $dsurname = $def[7];
    $ccompany = $def[8];
    $dbalance = $def[9];
    $damount = $def[10];

    if ($dbalance == "") {
        $newbalance = $damount;
    }
    else {
        $newbalance = $dbalance;
    }

    switch ($nextaction) {
```

I have tried adding

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT h.id, h.sid, h.did, h.nextaction, 
                            h.nextactiondate, d.company, d.name, 
                            d.surname, c.company, d.balance, 
                            d.amount 
                    from History h, Person d, Client c 
                    where h.sid=c.ref 
                      and d.id=h.did 
                      and nextactiondate between $dayEnd and $dayStart 
                    order by c.company desc 
                    WHERE c.statusRP = 'Open';");
```

but then I get errors on the line showing this:

```
while ($def = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you look closely you will see there is ALREADY a WHERE clause in the original query. Maybe you should look for another hobbie. Or read a SQL manual just for the fun of it

Comment: format your queries so you can actually understand what is in them

Comment: The error is because the query failed

Comment: Can we assume that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122821/php-mysql-display-open-satus) is now DEAD as you have added more tables to the query. If so please delete it. It is of no use to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `WHERE`, you need to join it with `AND`, and put it before the `ORDER BY`.

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT h.id, h.sid, h.did, h.nextaction, h.nextactiondate, d.company, d.name, d.surname, c.company, d.balance, d.amount 
    from History h, Person d, Client c 
    where h.sid=c.ref 
        and d.id=h.did 
        and nextactiondate between $dayEnd and $dayStart 
        AND c.statusRP = 'Open' 
        order by c.company desc;");
```

Additional notes: `$dayEnd` and `$dayStart` should probably be quoted, unless they're timestamps.

> You're wide open for SQL injection. The mysql_* functions are deprecated, and completely removed from PHP7. Switch to PDO or mysqli, and take advantage of prepared statements and variable binding, and you won't need to worry about quoting.